# How to change a non-alphabetically ordered Categorical column ordering in Polars Dataframe?

Tags: python-polars

I'm struggling to change the custom ordering of Polars Dataframe column after it has been created.

If I first create a Dataframe and set custom ordering for it the output is as expected:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{"cats": ["z", "z", "k", "a", "b"], "vals": [3, 1, 2, 2, 3]}
)

myorder=["k", "z", "b", "a"]

with pl.StringCache():
    pl.Series(myorder).cast(pl.Categorical)
    df=df.with_columns(pl.col('cats').cast(pl.Categorical))

print(df.sort(["cats"]))

shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ cats ┆ vals │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ cat  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ k    ┆ 2    │
│ z    ┆ 3    │
│ z    ┆ 1    │
│ b    ┆ 3    │
│ a    ┆ 2    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

However, if I want to change that custom ordering and I run the same logic again:

```
myorder=["b", "z", "k", "a"]

with pl.StringCache():
    pl.Series(myorder).cast(pl.Categorical)
    df=df.with_columns(pl.col('cats').cast(pl.Categorical))

print(df.sort(["cats"]))


shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ cats ┆ vals │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ cat  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ k    ┆ 2    │
│ z    ┆ 3    │
│ z    ┆ 1    │
│ b    ┆ 3    │
│ a    ┆ 2    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

...the custom ordering does not change. I believe this is because the cached categorical ordering does not change.

So, the question would be how can I change the custom ordering of Categorical column after it has been created?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is how Categoricals are supposed to behave but my first thought was to try `.cast(pl.Utf8).cast(pl.Categorical)` and that seems to "work".

Comment: @jqurious is right. If you try to cast a categorical to a categorical then it doesn't do anything because the source and target are the same dtype.  You've got to turn them back into utf and back to cat to force it to reset its index.

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing this at some point, but then I couldn't reproduce it so I thought it just worked by coincidence. But yeah, I probably had some other mistake then because it works as you described. I will add answer to the question with code example if someone else happens to stumble on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting the column to pl.Utf8 resets the index and the Categorical column is updated after casting it back.

```
myorder=["b", "z", "k", "a"]

with pl.StringCache():
    pl.Series(myorder).cast(pl.Categorical)
    df=df.with_columns(pl.col('cats').cast(pl.Utf8).cast(pl.Categorical))
```